# Overlapping tabbed containers list items

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Sure this is a simple solution to this, but I am scratching my head trying to solve it. I have a tabbed container with about 3 list items, each of which have hyperlinks in them. When I reduce the size of my browser window [let's say from the right] it does not hide the element to the extreme right, instead the size of the list item reduces and then adjusts itself right below the width of the other two list items.

I have the min width set to the same as that of the width of the element.

Where do I need to tweak ?

Here is the semantic structure

```
<div id = "tabbed">
  <ul>
     <li><a href = "#tab_1">Tab 1</a></li> <!-- 3 list items -->
  </ul>
  <div class = "tabs" id = "tab_1"> <!--3 tabs, each tab corresponds to the link in the list item -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#tabbed
{
width :80%;
margin:auto;
margin-top:20px;
}

#tabbed ul{
margin:0px;
margin-top:15px;
}

#tabbed li
{
display: inline-block;
list-style-type:none;
border:1px solid #ccc;
border-bottom: 0px;
border-top-left-radius:4px;
border-top-right-radius:4px;
margin-right:5px;
margin-top:5px;
padding:4px 4px 10px 4px;
width: 30%;
background:#87CEEB;
}

#tabbed a{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color: #7F818B;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: Posting either your code, or preferably, a link to a live example would help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please give us some example html and CSS/styles for what you are doing. The way a browser will wrap content depends very much on the implementation. I assume you are using the CSS display: inline to make the list horizontal?

Comment: using display:inline-block to set it horizontal, for some reason dispaly:inline does not quite behave the way it ought to, probably overrides some other css stylesheet I am using here,  but I'll get to that later....thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to look at, I can suggest the following:

try

```
your_div {overflow:hidden;}
```

For starters,

Secondly, min-width is only observed by only half the browsers out there. I would suggest trying a different approach for setting minimum width, as well as a code example for best results:)

Comment: nope, overflow:hidden did not quite solve the problem, did you want to take a look at the code I just put in and see what's up ?